# How to show outer equatorial circle on solid torus?

Tags: graphics3d

In the following graphic of a solid torus, how can I show in the plane z = 0 just the outer "equatorial circle", and not the smaller circle inside, *without* parameterizing that equatorial circle?

```
With[{R = 2, r = 0.5}, 
 Show[{RegionPlot3D[(R - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^2 + z^2 <= r^2, {x, -3, 
     3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -1, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 5, PlotPoints -> 60, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2], Mesh -> None, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
    Ticks -> None, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.5}],
   SliceContourPlot3D[(R - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]) + 
     r, {"ZStackedPlanes", {0}}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -1, 1},
    Contours -> 1, ContourShading -> None,
    ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
    Ticks -> None, Boxed -> False]}, ImageSize -> Scaled[0.7]]
 ]
```

[image: Solid torus with equator and spurious circle]

Comment: Don't use a contour plot, use this: [`ResourceFunction["Circle3D"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/Circle3D) in a `Graphics3D`

Comment: Add `BoundaryStyle -> None, RegionFunction -> 
 Function[{x, y, z, f}, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] > r]` into `SliceContourPlot3D`.

Comment: Simple solution: Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.5], Torus[{0, 0, 0}, {5, 10}]}, Black, 
  Torus[{0, 0, 0}, {10, 10.2}]}]``

Comment: Solution using `RegionFunction` is closest in spirit to my original. The `ResourceFunction["Circle3D"]` seems awkward in that default has circle in plane perpendicular to x-axis. The solution using `Torus` sort of defeats my purpose in actually using equation of the torus, and its equatorial circle becomes a tube.

Comment: How about `plot /. {dir_, l1_Line, l2_Line} :> {dir, l1}` to remove the offending line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `RegionFunction` and `BoundaryStyle`:

```
With[{R = 2, r = 0.5},
 Show[{
   RegionPlot3D[
    (R - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^2 + z^2 <= r^2
    , {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -1, 1}
    , MaxRecursion -> 5, PlotPoints -> 60, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2], 
    Mesh -> None, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Ticks -> None, 
    Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.5}],
   SliceContourPlot3D[
    (R - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]) + r
    , {"ZStackedPlanes", {0}}
    , {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -1, 1}
    , Contours -> 1, ContourShading -> None, 
    ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
    Ticks -> None, Boxed -> False, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 > R^2], 
    BoundaryStyle -> None
    ]}
  , ImageSize -> Scaled[0.7]]]
```

[image]